# Paint trail that follows touch input

Tags: java, android, touch, paint

I am trying to create a music pad that plays music when the screen is touched. I also want there to be a trail that follows the users finger.

[image: a busy cat]

As you can see in the image I can draw to the screen and it follows the touch but it doesnt fade away and I'm left with a massive coloured line.

I am using the paint class in android

and here is the code im using to draw

```
public class SingleTouchEventView extends View{

 private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "Velocity";
 private VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker = null;
 public Paint paint = new Paint();
 public Path path = new Path();
 int sr = 44100;
 boolean isRunning = true;

public SingleTouchEventView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

super(context, attrs);


int [] mColors={0xFFFF0000,0xFFFF00FF,0xFF0000FF,0xFF00FFFF,0xFF00FF00,0xFF000000,0xFFFFFFFF,0xFFFFFF00,0xFFFF0000};
Shader s=new SweepGradient(0,0,mColors,null);
paint.setShader(s);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setStrokeWidth(6f);
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

  }

 @Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  float eventX = event.getX();
  float eventY = event.getY();

case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two paths you can go by,

II) Easy One: On fast intervals, blend the canvas with a bitmap or canvas that is original background to this canvas. This blending can be done via drawing background over this canvas with some alpha depending on how fast you want old pixels to fade away. This is highly inefficient, ugly with high probability, but Easy Thing To Do.

I) Right One: Fade custom Pixels-Paths that have time state attached. Attach time data to every pixel or path, latter is better. Define a `threshold` for lifespan of element. Redraw this pixel/path on the canvas with density (alpha channel) calculated by delta (now - p.time) and threshold. `1 - (now - p.time)/threshold` is a good start. Note that this is harder, more efficient, more desired and more tweak-able and The Right Thing To Do.

Answer (score 0):

Call `canvas.drawRGB()` in case ACTION_UP with the RGB color that matches your background color. You need a reference to the canvas in your `onDraw()`